# Why do I get an indent between two objects after adding a Subsurf modifier?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

This is my first post. I hope you can help.

I have an object with an extruded face, that is slightly smaller than the width/height of the main object. When adding the subsurface modifier, at the join I am getting a indent between the two objects.

I have tried extra loop cuts, cut it either distorts the extruded parts shape, or creates a strange hard line.

[image: Object with extruded face]
[image: loop cut added]

Comment: it looks like you have an inner face, plus what are those faces going upwards?

Comment: I have looked inside my model, and there appears to be no face inside.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PKSDgQVK" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PKSDgQVK/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just bad topology, you have ngons that are stretched by the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, use the knife tool and create edges on the top to only keep quads:

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you. That has done it.  I have been stuck on this for about 2 weeks. It has been driving me crazy.